# how to get the number of permutations from a finite list

Tags: permutations

I'm trying to get the number of permutations from a table that looks like this:

[image]
is it (number of providers) * (number of machine categories) * (proxy providers) * (proxy subnets) * (websites)?

Comment: It's not obvious (to me at least) what a "permutation from a table" is.  There is no row that has $P2$ and $PS4$...is that relevant?

Comment: @lulu well this table isn't comprehensive... that's the point of the question... ie there _could_ be a row that has a p2 and a ps4.. ok I guess the question is: what is the maximum amount of permutations?

Comment: Ok.  In that case, yes.  Just multiply the number of options in each category, as you suggest.

Comment: @lulu and so how is that described in fancy mathematical notational format? help me out here i'm making a presentation and I wanna give the folks the impression that I'm a smart guy :)

Comment: # Permutations $=\prod_{i=1}^kn_i$  where there are $k$ categories and $n_i$ denotes the number of options in each category.

Comment: one last quesiton @lulu: what software do you use to produce that mathematical stuff? ie this (∏ki=1ni=∏i=1kni  )i wanna sound and _look_ smart you know

Comment: Sure.  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.  The code I used was "=\prod_{i=1}^kn_i"  surrounded by dollar signs (so the compiler knows it has to do some formatting.

Comment: also is there a resource online or some calculator app or something that can calculate the number of those permutations, if i use the same format you suggested?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/ is a good online resource for symbolic computation.  It may take a while to learn how to ask it questions of this type but if you are used to Mathematica the language and syntax should be familiar.

Comment: @lulu interesting.. i used the formatter on mathJax, and I got exactly what you showed me, however as soon as I pasted the ascii code into slack.. i got some gibberish.. i'm guessing the outpout of this math jax needs to be put in an application that understand that formatting

Comment: never mind i understood what's going on now

Comment: so humour me @lulu, what would the above formula look like on the wolframalpha.com input?

Comment: Sorry, running out to catch a plane.  There are plenty of online tutorials for Mathmatica and such.  Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56987/discussion-between-abbood-and-lulu).

Comment: As I say, I can't talk any more.  Good luck!